# How to pass arguments to custom template tags from templates of type queryset dict

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a context of variable say 'a' which is of type queryset and in the queryset there are fields of type dict. So how should I pass field name as an argument to the template tags

```py
@register.filter
def total(a, key):
    total_ = 0
    for d in a:
        if key in d:
            total_ += d[key]
    return total_

1. a|total: b 
2. a|total a b


context: {'a': <QuerySet [{'b':1, 'c':1},{'b':2, 'c':2}]}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the template, rather than when you create the queryset in the view? This seems like a job for annotations.

Comment: And what does "none of this works for me" mean? What happened, exactly?